# Django ModelChoiceField in forms not displaying properly

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I use the following forms for creating a question. The `community` here is a specific community a user belongs to.

```
class Question(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(Question, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["community"].queryset = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=self.user.communities.all())

    community = forms.ChoiceField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

The corresponding view is this.

```
def add_question(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form = Question(user=request.user)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'question.html', context)
```

I am calling `form.as_table` appropriately in the template file.
The object is being rendered properly but I cannot see any data in the dropdown. 
Why is this problem occurring and what should be done to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for your `community` field. A regular `ChoiceField` takes `choices` as an argument, not `queryset`.

When you set the `queryset` attribute in your `__init__` method, assign a queryset to it, not a form field.

Putting it altogether, you have:

```
class Question(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["community"].queryset = self.user.communities.all()

    community = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Community.objects.none())
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: Yes, I used Question. Sorry for the typo. Now, when I use ````ModelChoiceField````, I get TypeError :
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: See my updated answer. `ModelChoiceField` requires a queryset. You can use the empty queryset, since you set the real queryset in the `__init__` method.